# Novelty detection in signal data using machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, detection

I want to detect anomalies in a signal. If I understand it correctly this is called novelty detection. I have lots of 'good' examples and only 2 or 3 'bad' examples.

This is how the signal looks like: [image] These are all good examples.
An example of a bad signal can be seen here: [image]

Not all examples are of the same length making it more difficult to classify. I have some experience with machine learning and deep learning (classifying images), but none with this kind of data.

So far I have only found methods that use labeled data with good and bad examples, and methods that use examples which are all of the same length.

Does anyone know how I can create solution for this problem (preferably available in Python)?

Comment: I would suggest you post this question either on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ or https://ai.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will you be using images for doing the classification or the underlying values?

Comment: The underlying values (second based)

Comment: Check these: https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11374/unsupervised-learning-for-anomaly-detection & https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11218/which-unsupervised-anomaly-detection-algorithms-are-there